# Using storyboard to seque from a tableview to a webview

Tags: ios, webview, storyboard, tableview

Good afternoon all.
I'm pretty new to iOS programming.  Been developing for VB for years and this is a huge difference.

I've written a small Storyboarded app, with a splash, a tableview, and ultimately a web view to display a web page.  The Storyboard works great, the tableview works great, however, when I try to push the URL to the web view, all I get is:
"Application tried to push a nil view controller on target

I've read that i did not alloc correctly somewhere, but hesitate to copy ALL of my code here as that's a lot of wasted space.

When pressing one of the table rows, this is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

NSURL *urlInSafari = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlInSafari];

[self.detailViewController.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

}
```

I am not sure what this does, but when the app was created by default it stuck in a label that would take a date/time when a table row was pressed.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
}
}
```

Do I need to change the destinationViewController to the WebView that is on my DetailViewController?

Everything works but the opening of the link on the WebView.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like self.detailViewController is nil. If detailViewController is an outlet make sure it is connected in your XIB file.

Comment: Maybe that's it.  The *webView on the detailViewController is connected in the xib, but not the detailViewController itself?